# Activate mysql.trace_mode and apache crashes

Tags: php, xdebug, wapiti

Wapiti security scanner HOWTO tell to activate

```
mysql.trace_mode = On
```

in PHP config file to help it find security flaws. But with this option activated, Apache crash a lot, even when I just browse my website. This option seems valuable, but unusable for me for now.

I have an Ubuntu precise (12.04) amd64, and

```
i   apache2                         - Métapaquet pour le serveur HTTP Apache    
i   apache2-mpm-prefork             - Serveur HTTP Apache - modèle traditionnel 
i   apache2-utils                   - utility programs for webservers           
i A apache2.2-bin                   - Fichiers binaires communs du serveur HTTP 
i A apache2.2-common                - Fichiers communs du serveur HTTP Apache   
i   epi-apache-certificats          - certificats epiconcept pour apache        
i A libapache-pom-java              - Maven metadata for all Apache Software pro
i   libapache2-mod-php5             - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting langu
```

apache2 -v :

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 12 2013 13:37:10
```

php5 -v :

```
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep  4 2013 20:00:51) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: I just though it may be xdebug the guilty one. I try.

Answer (score 0):

Xdebug was the guilty one, when I unload it the test run fine.